# Trouble displaying created_at value in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm trying to display the created_at column in one of my views and I'm not having any luck. When I try using the below:

`{{ date('d M Y - H:i:s', $object->created_at) }}`

I get the following error: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given.
So I use dd() on $object->created_at and it gives me this:

`object(Carbon\Carbon)#555 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-01-22 14:36:37.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "Africa/Johannesburg" }`

So naturally I tried accessing the date with a foreach loop which didn't work and I also tried $object->created_at->date which gave me an error "Unknown getter 'date'"
How do I access the date from created_at?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Laravel uses Carbon. Then try this:

```
{{ date('d M Y - H:i:s', $object->created_at->timestamp) }}
```

Or this is the same without date function

```
{{ $object->created_at->format('d M Y - H:i:s') }}
```

Or use any method documented in the [Carbon API](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-getters)

Answer (score 4):

This is another method -

```
{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($list->created_at)) }}
```